Projective varieties with non-isomorphic Chow motive but isomorphic rational Chow rings
I would like to have examples of smooth projective varieties $X$ and $Y$ that have the same rational Chow ring but non-isomorphic Chow motives $h(X)$ and $h(Y)$.

You can consider two non-isogenous elliptic curves, or even two curves of higher genus with non-isogenous Jacobians. The genus of the curves need not even be the same, as long as both are positive. Higher dimensional examples can be constructed by, for example, taking products with $\mathbb{P}^1$.
